# PHP Script Won't Upload to FTP Server -

Tags: php, ftp

Having spent hours on this, I am out of luck. This script worked perfectly until yesterday. The script generates XML and dumps it as a file (5kb) to a remote FTP server. The script has not changed, nor has our host changed anything. The FTP server company has changed something (they said IP change yesterday) (but claims nothing apart from this). This IP resulted in a different ftp_server which has worked fine.

When I attempt to run the script, I get the following error regardless of whether "ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);" is there or not / disabled:

```
Warning: ftp_fput() [function.ftp-fput]: Opening ASCII mode data connection in ...
```

Then it gives the line which contains "FTP_ASCII" below.

When I have the ft_pasv section there only (as per original script), an additional error of the following still appears with the following:

```
Warning: ftp_fput() [function.ftp-fput]: data_accept: SSL/TLS handshake failed in ...
```

This is for the same line as the above error.

They were originally on a self-signed SSL. Now, due to my issue, they are now on a 'correct' SSL issued by a well known company. No errors display on Filezilla upon connecting.

**Importantly, I can upload via Filezilla with no issues, with or without passive mode**

Code above the below code in the script is correct for generating the file as it appears on the script page, once loaded. It just won't dump the file on the server. Here is the connecting to the server bit:

```
//Connect to the FTP server

$ftp_server = 'import.ftpserverdomain.com';
$ftp_user_name = 'CORRECT-USERNAME';
$ftp_user_pass = 'CORRECT-PASSWORD';

// set up basic ssl connection
$conn_id = ftp_ssl_connect($ftp_server) or die("CONNECTION ERROR");

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass) or die("LOGIN ERROR");

$directory = ftp_pwd($conn_id); // /
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);


$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
fputs($fp,$file_contents);
fclose($fp);



$fp = fopen($filename, 'r');

$path_with_file = $directory.$filename;

if (ftp_fput($conn_id, $path_with_file, $fp, FTP_ASCII)) {
    echo "Successfully Uploaded $File\n";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem while uploading $File\n";
}

fclose($fp);

unlink($filename);

ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Any help is much appreciated. Sorry if I lacked any information. I'll be happy to provide any.

Comment: If the FTP service changed the settings, have they not provided you with new information about it? Anyone who makes changes without added support, should in fact do just that. Have you tried using different settings? Try using the same FTP login as you do with FileZilla.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. They say it is just an IP change that has happened, including a domain switch. This switch works as Filezilla now operates. Therefore, they claim nothing else needs to be provided to us. I am sort of need in some code help as my developer has deserted me! With the exception of passive mode, ftp_server, ftp_user_name, ftp_user_pass and ftp_ssl_connect, what else can I try to replicate Filezilla settings I am on? Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Have you tried `ftp_connect` instead of `ftp_ssl_connect`? Maybe the SSL socket can't be accessed anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your input again. I tried this and it stated, "Warning: ftp_login() [function.ftp-login]: Policy requires SSL" which is says in Filefilla too without SSL. Do you have any other ideas? Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome (again) ;-) Sorry I don't know what else to tell you. Many a times for me before, my (then) hosting company which I "no longer use", used to change things without added important tech support. I'm sure it has something to do with your FTP service/hosting company, and then again it could very well be a "propagation" issue, where it could start working within 24hrs., very hard to say though. I wish I could be of more help.

Comment: Thanks. I think I might try running the script directly on this remote FTP company's server as I have a hunch too it is to with the host. It is just strange it stopped working on the day the IP changes. But yes it could be propagation with a change of IP. We shall see tomorrow. Thanks again!

Comment: Upon further investigation, it is actually creating the file name on the server but not 'writing' any of the data too it i.e the file size remains at 0. Would this help in anyway? Thank you

Comment: It seems like what's happening is that you're writing content, and then it gets deleted by this `unlink($filename);` --- therefore the file deleted afterwards. Comment out or delete that line then try it again.

Comment: For future use, in case someone else hops in our comments, use the `@` symbol followed by my name, so that I will personally get notification.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I was getting rather excited until the errors were shown again! I have commented it out and try deleting the code to no success. Is there any possibility of setting a port number to connect to or mimic FTP that connects explicit FTP over TLS as that appears to work only in a direct FTP program? Thank you.

Comment: You can use something to the affect of `$ftp_server = 'import.ftpserverdomain.com:80';` depending on which port you'll be using. I suggest you Google "ftp port php" see what other results you will find that may help. Ports are usually added using `:portnumber` --- `portnumber` being the port number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue. Hopefully this helps someone. The issue turned out to be server (HostGator). They do not allow FTP over TLS on a shared account.

Despite this working for a year, switching hosts resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like PHP can't find your CA Certs, if you are running this on a linux box, this is something I have encountered before. Some searching should help but basically PHP's OpenSSL integration needs pointing at your cacerts directory so it can use these to validate the SSL connection it is attempting to make.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please add some code showing how to point to the ca-certs directory?